# How to open a new view with a mapview when you click in a button in the actual view

Tags: java, android

I need example code for android (java):

- I have a view with a button
- When the user clics the button, I want a new view to be opened
- I want a mapview in the new opened view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an activity for showing map and then give that intent inside your button click. For creating that map activity, the below link will helo you out.

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: thnks...that just releived me from a huge burden